# Passing a regular parameter through the generateUrl function in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, url, redirect, parameter-passing

I'm redirecting to the entity_show route through the createAction.  In the create logic, I'm assigning a non-entity variable ($credited) to 'credited' or 'not credited', which I'm then trying to pass to the showAction (entity_show route) through the return call of

```
this->redirect(generateUrl(entity_show, array('id' => $entity->getId(), $credited)));
```

I've tried this several ways,

```
array(..., $credited)
array(..., 'credited' => $credited)
array(..., true/false)
```

but none of these values are being correctly passed into the showAction, even though I have the parameter defined.

```
public function showAction($id, $credited = 'credited') { ... }
```

(I need the default value in case I call showAction from a place other than createAction, where $credited is undefined)

The problem is that in showAction, $credited always falls back to its default value, even when in createAction the value passed was 'not credited', meaning the parameter is not getting passed to showAction at all like I intend it to.

**Is it possible to pass a variable through generateUrl() as a *normal* function parameter instead of something inherently tied to the URL?**

Ideally, if I can get my $credited value passed from createAction into showAction, then in showAction I can return $credited to the twig view, where I can use some twig logic to display custom text depending on what value $credited holds.

```
return array(
    'entity'      => $entity,
    'credited'    => $credited,
    'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple array stuff:

```
this->redirect(generateUrl('entity_show', array(
    'id' => $entity->getId(), 
    'credited' => $credited
)));
```

I am assuming of course that entity_show route has id and credited defined.

Updated in response to the first comment.

Try:
    echo generateUrl('entity_show', array(
        'id' => $entity->getId(), 
        'credited' => $credited
    )); die();

I suspect that your entity_show route is not correctly defined.  Consider updating your question with the route definition as well as the results of the above test.  Actually, your browser should be showing the redirected url as well.

Comment: Sorry, I tried my best to explain this, I tried this method, exactly, however $credited isn't getting passed into showAction, because it always assumes its default value, even when I'm passing it through this logic you've suggested, with $credited being a value different from the default value assigned in showAction.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I've decided to go with a different strategy, adding a database field since I realized I will need to be updating this anyway with some logic irrelevant to this topic.  Still though, I went ahead and echoed what you asked.  /symfony2/web/app_dev.php/myentity/4308?credited=not+credited is what is output.  I just wanted $credited to be passed into the showAction function, I don't care how it got there, but I needed to use generateUrl to do it. But not anymore, I'm going to use Doctrine and flashbag.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok.  However, assuming that /myentity is mapped to showAction then your $credited variable will be set.  If you think it is not then you should examine why you think so.  It's possible that you may not understand Symfony 2's redirect capability.

Comment: The route is /{id}, the method is GET.  You've seen what I had for the return (from createAction) and the parameters that I'm trying to take into showAction.  You've seen the generated redirect URL (goes to /{id} with an added GET attribute of ?credited=not+credited.  All that seems kosher to me, however the $credited value, 'not credited',  from createAction is *not* being passed into showAction, and therefore showAction is assigning $credited to its default value, of 'credited'.  Its certainly possible I may not understand, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: And you are actually redirecting?  Your createAction has a  "return $this>redirect..."

Comment: The redirect is occurring.  Everything is working, except `$credited` is not getting passed into the `showAction($id, $credited = 'credited')` parameter, and its default value is being assigned.